# React JS - webpack throws error with loading JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

Trying out a simple React JS application and below is the snapshot of index.js. A sample json data file is kept under src/data/ folder.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Menu from "./components/Menu";
import data from "./data/recipes.json";

render(<Menu recipes={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

webpack is failing with below error. Tried download json-loader and have added it in the package.json but still getting the same error.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import data from "./data/recipes.json";
| 
> render(<Menu recipes={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
```

webpack config

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist", "assets"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }]
  }  
};
```

Comment: Can you provide your webpack configuration file? At the very least, the relevant part with the json loader?

Comment: The error tells you that it is an issue with Webpack not being able to load the file. You could either look into bringing in a [json loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json5-loader/), or you could switch to something like [parcel](https://parceljs.org/), which is what I would recommend when trying out React. Webpack takes a lot of configuration, which gives you a lot more control, but parcel is meant to just work out of the box, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Added webpack config to the question

Comment: json loader was installed and added in package.json under "devDependencies". Is there anything else needed ? or some issue with this ?
"json-loader": "^0.5.7",

Comment: Have you tried json5-loader? https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json5-loader/

Answer (score 1):

⚠️ Since webpack >= v2.0.0, importing of JSON files will work by default. You might still want to use this if you use a custom file extension. See the v1.0.0 -> v2.0.0 Migration Guide for more information

This is commonly a result of broken imports. Make sure the webpack.config.js is at the root of your project i.e. at the same level as src.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to embed the JSON in index.js itself as a constant, still the webpack build is failing with same error on the same line. So it looks like the issue is not really with reading the json file but seems like the issue is with binding the JSON to the render method.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 43:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (43:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   ]
| 
> render(<Menu recipes={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```